# Excel Form Creation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating a form in Excel but want for the words to end at page margin and continue to next cell.

I have word wrap turned off and the cells within margins are merged.

I am new to Excel and need some direction as to how it works effectively.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried adding a text box? Keeping in mind Excel doesn't act like Word when it comes to page margins because its not a word processor, does the form have to be in Excel?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution for this, other than a text box or putting word wrap back on for those cells the only thing I can think of is macro on a `worksheet_change` event which has the potential to slow your worksheet right down and could cause issues if it isn't set up right.

Comment: (1) You may want to define the question a bit more clearly without asking "how it works effectively". (2) Do you have to use Excel for this? Any reason not to use Word or any other software more specific to building forms?

Answer (score -1):

Thinking you may mean a template such as an registration form rather than an object form like a textbox.

With default settings and column widths, selecting View > Page Layout, 9 columns are displayed on each printed page. A simple idea would be to select columns A-I for a given number of rows, select Merge Cells, and turn on Wrap Text. This would allow for a simple text entry box.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)